# What is the proper way to prove this?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

First of all, here is the question I am trying to answer for context.
[image]

I can see that the statement

$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} , \exists y \in \mathbb{Z}((x\leq y ) \wedge (x+y=0)) $

negates to

$\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}((x>y)\lor(x + y\neq 0))$

At least I hope that's right, or my logic is a lot worse than I thought.

Anyway, when I translate the first statement into English, it says, "for all integers x, there exists an integer y which is greater than or equal to x AND x+y = 0".

Now, when I let x = 1, I can see that the statement is blatantly false.  Any y which is greater than one will never equal zero when added to one.  The thing is I have no idea how to write this formally.  I am a software person and proofs have never been a strong point.  Thus, I humbly seek the mathematical wisdom of this awesome community which has already saved me many times before.

Comment: While you are correct, and there are already good answers, I would suggest that you can transform your negation using $\neg p \lor q \iff p \to q$, that is $$\exists x \in\mathbb{Z}.\ \forall y\in\mathbb{Z}.\ (x \leq y) \to (x + y \neq 0)$$ which is equivalent to $\exists x.\ \forall y \geq x.\ x + y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is perfectly fine, if you meant $x+y \neq 0$ in the last line

You need to prove that "EXISTS a $x \in \mathbb{Z}$" such that etc., and you just did with $x=1$.

If you need some things, write:

$x=1$. Then take $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. If ($1\leq y$) then $(y+1 > y-1 \geq 0$), so that $OR$ is true for all $y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your negation is not quite right (although I suspect more a typo than anything). It should be
$$
\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall y \in \mathbb{Z} \big((x > y) \vee (x + y \neq 0)\big)
$$

Anyhow, that aside: The first statement is false. If $x > 0$, then any $y \geq x > 0$ as well. Given that, for any $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y \geq x$, we must have $x + y > x + 0 > 0$. Thus for $x = 1$, there does not exist a $y$ as specified in the statement. QED.

Comment: Oh, yes. I left out the y and didn't notice.  But yes, that was a typo, so I don't feel too terrible about it.

Comment: That's what I figured. I couldn't see how you would have got from the one statement to the one you wrote otherwise.